# Allowing data additions but not deletions in a MS Access Form's Textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, textbox, keyboard-events, ms-access-forms

I am not sure if this is possible, but I would like to be able to restrict anyone from changing/deleting the current text in a textbox, but allow them to add to it?  This way there is no way to accidentally delete data, but if something was wrong, the user can add information/clarification.

I tried using the KeyDown and KeyPress events to do this (something like below):

```
Private Sub TxtIssueDescription_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

If Len(Me.TxtIssueDescription.OldValue) > Len(Me.TxtIssueDescription.Value) Then
    Me.TxtIssueDescription.Value = Me.TxtIssueDescription.OldValue
End If

End Sub
```

But since it doesn't fire after every character that is typed, it doesn't work (ie .OldValue = "Hello" and .Value = "Good Bye" - not right!)

I am really looking for a creative idea to this because I don't think using events will work.

Comment: Does all of the text need to be in the same textbox? You could unlink the textbox from the table, and then use a label or locked text box to contain the current text and append any data from another textbox into the record.

Comment: Would be better to have related table where each 'comment' is a record. Otherwise, maybe explore Long Text (Memo) type field and ColumnHistory - no VBA needed. Or use @Warcupine suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps try the [Textbox.Dirty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.dirty) event and [Textbox.OnDirty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.ondirty) property. The Dirty event occurs when the content changes and is a control event, instead of a keyboard event, so should get triggered every time.

Answer (score 0):

In the On Get Focus event for the Control, check if the Control is Empty.

In pseudocode:

```
If Control Is Empty Then Exit
Else Set Enabled = No and Locked = Yes
```

That should do it. If you want to do this for several Controls, just make the above a Procedure that accepts the current Control as a parameter and call the procedure from within the Event Handler. If you make it a Function, then you can just put the function call right in the Property Sheet like this "=LockControl(Me!CurrentControl)". I prefer to use an Event Handler.

Here is how I check for Empty Controls:

```
Public Function IsEmptyControl(ctl As Variant) As Boolean
 
' ****************************************************************************
' PURPOSE: Determines if control is empty, that is, either all blanks or null
'
' AUTHOR: Paul Strauss
'         Paul@PStrauss.net
'
' DATE:   December 31, 2000
'
' NOTES: Returns True if control is empty
'
' CHANGE LOG:
'
' ****************************************************************************
 
On Error GoTo Err_IsEmptyControl

IsEmptyControl = IsNull(ctl) Or (Len(Trim(ctl)) = 0)

Exit_IsEmptyControl:
 
   Exit Function
 
Err_IsEmptyControl:
 
   Select Case Err.Number
 
      Case Else
 
         Call ErrHandler(Object:=CodeProject.Name, procedure:="IsEmptyControl", ErrNum:=Err.Number, ErrDesc:=Err.Description)

         Resume Exit_IsEmptyControl
 
   End Select
```

End Function